# Allow a-z, A-Z, 0-9, space and -. preg_match

Tags: preg-match

How can I allow a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and space with preg_match.

I currently have the following:

`if (!preg_match("/^[_a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $name))`

Also a side-question, does any of you know a good guide to learn preg_match.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you

```
    <?php
    $result = preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \s]+$/", $name));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just give `space` and `"-"` in your brackets `[ ]`
example

```
<?php
$name = "A- "; 
if(preg_match("/^[_a-zA-Z0-9- ]+$/", $name))
{
echo "hello";
}
?>
```

and a good site for studying : [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

**only [a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and Space] allow. We delete the first space with LTRIM.**

```
    <?php
$name = "Hasan Yİlmaz SÃ„Â°MFER "; 
if(ltrim(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZığüşöçİGÜŞÖÇ0-9- ]+$/', $name2), ' '))
    {
        echo $name;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Using `/^[a-zA-Z'- ]+$/` Shows the below given warning

> "preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character
>   class at offset 10"

Instead of the above-mentioned code, you can use `/^[a-zA-Z' -]+$/`. This will not show the warning.!

Comment: This does not really answer the question though